# Why don't custom Windows Explorer context menu entries appear?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, context-menu

I want to add a custom context menu item to Windows Explorer in Windows 10, so that when I right-click on certain types of file, I can run a particular application on the file.  I have found various guides on the web with similar solutions to the StackOverflow question [Add menu item to Windows Context Menu only for specific filetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123762/add-menu-item-to-windows-context-menu-only-for-specific-filetype).

From what I understand, if I want the context menu to appear for `.JPG` files, I check the registry and find that Win10 gives these the `jpegfile` type.  I need to use `regedit` to add the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\jpegfile\shell\myapp\command`, and set its default value to the path to my app.

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work: I don't see any new context menu item.  Also, I noticed in the registry that another menu item had previously been added for `jpegfile` (Open in GIMP).  It doesn't work either, so I presume it's not just me failing to follow the instructions properly.  I've checked that the paths are correct for both my app and the GIMP executable. I have also tried both a standard right-click and a shift-right-click to display the context menu.

- Is there some trick to getting this style of context menu to display?
- Has something changed in Windows 10, so that this type of hack no longer works?  If so, is there an alternative method?
- Could something else be inhibiting display of these menu items?  Where should I start looking?

Comment: How did you get on with the other answer on this page (another variant of it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39551212/adding-context-menu-item-to-specific-extension-via-registry) where it suggests using SystemFileAssociations rather than Software\Classes? Was the GIMP association created by the GIMP installer? If it was then re-running the installer might fix that association.

Comment: Is `.jpeg` AND `.jpg` associated with `jpegfile`. Context menus registry entries are valid on the extension as well. And use HKEY_CURRENT_USER as settings there will override local machine. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT is a merged view of User and System.

Comment: @Mark Yes, both `.jpeg` and `.jpg` were associated with `jpegfile`.  I tried setting the key on the extension directly too, and that didn't work either.

Comment: @trapper_hag Thanks, I'd missed that. Using `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\image\Shell\` worked a treat for all image types. If you add it as an answer, I'll accept it.  Incidentally, I updated to the current GIMP, which replaced the broken menu item entry, and added GIMP to the 'Open with...' menu via a different registry mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Glad to hear you got it sorted)

Try editing `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.jpg\Shell` rather than `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\jpegfile\shell`. See here for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42776281/957246