# webp files not treated as "image" type in Windows Explorer context menu

Tags: windows-explorer, context-menu, file-types, mime-types, webp

I am trying to add custom items to the Windows Explorer context menu in Windows 10 & Windows 11 for image files. I want the custom items to appear (only) for all image types. As far as I can tell the problem described below is the same in both versions of Windows:

I have a python script that converts image files to PNG format, and have created a menu item that works for files with the "image" type, by merging the following into the registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\RunPython]
@=""
"icon"="C:\\Users\\Username\\Pictures\\python.ico"
"MUIVerb"="Run Python Script"
"SubCommands"=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\RunPython\shell\ConvertToPNG]
@=""
"MUIVerb"="Convert to PNG"
"icon"="C:\\Users\\Username\\Pictures\\python.ico"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\RunPython\shell\ConvertToPNG\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\Username\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\python.exe\" \"C:\\Project\\Python\\Images\\convert_image.py\" --source \"%1\" --image_type \"PNG\""
```

This seems to work for image types such as JPG, PNG, etc. When I right-click on those files an entry appears in the context menu as **Run Python Script** with a python icon. However, when I right-click on a WEBP file the **Run Python Script** entry in the context menu is missing. As far as I am aware, WEBP is an image file type so I'd expect the context menu to appear for these files too.

*Q: Why doesn't Windows Explorer show the menu items for WEBP files?*

---

**Workaround:** I can get this to appear by editing the **.reg** file above, changing `\image\` to `\.webp\` in the Registry key paths and merging back into the Registry. I'd prefer not to have to do this.

**Research:**

1. I believe I'm correct that WEBP should be classed as "images" since they have the [**image/webp** MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Image_types#webp_image).
2. When I check the HKCR, HKCU and HKLM locations in the registry for **.webp** files I see this, which looks correct:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.webp]
"ContentType"="image/webp"
"PerceivedType"="image"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.webp]
<no entries>

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.webp]
"ContentType"="image/webp"
"PerceivedType"="image"
```

3. Other StackExchange questions:

- [Why don't custom Windows Explorer context menu entries appear?](https://superuser.com/q/1559551/543612)
- [Add menu item to Windows context menu only for specific filetype](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2123762/5771128)
- [Adding context menu item to specific extension via registry](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39551212/5771128)

---

Comment: You might try adding the extension to the **KindMap** under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`.  does it have a *ProgID* and associated app as well?

Comment: I have had a look in the **KindMap** key; there is already a REG_SZ entry for **.webp** with a value of **picture**. As a sanity check, **.jpeg** has the same setting.

Comment: There are some associated **ProgIDs** which I excluded in the `.REG` exports above. Looking up the IDs find apps such as Paint, etc. which I do see when I right-click and expand the "Open With" menu option.